# Check for existance of list item in string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an `string Array` and a `List<Class>`

```
string[] TypeArray = Type.Trim().Split(',');
List<ClassName> TypeList = obj.GetList(id);
```

Now I want to check whether any value in `sting[]` present in `List<ClassName>`.

Currently I am able to do this by using `Nested Foreach` as below::

```
foreach (var Type in TypeList)
{
    foreach (string SingleType in TypeArray)
    {
        if (Type .Vaue.ToLower().Equals(SingleType.ToLower()))
        {
            IsValidType = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not using Entity Framework in this.

Comment: I'd argue the given code sample is probably a bit too small for us to give a meaningful review. The code in the question is also broken, so there is that.

Comment: Very snippety, don't migrate this.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool IsPresent = TypeArray.Any(p=>TypeList.Any(x=>x.Value.Equals(p, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
```

Comment: It should be `p.SingleType`. Better solution then mine +1.

Comment: @RahulSingh SingleType was a variable name inside foreach to represent the currently iterating item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
bool IsPresent = TypeList.Any(x => TypeArray
                                    .Any(z => x.Value.ToLower() == z.ToLower());
```

Since you want to check for equality I am using `==` you can also `Contains` if you wish to match.

You need to import `System.Linq` in your code. If you are are targeting .Net framework 3.5 or greater its assembly will be automatically referenced.

Comment: @Rahul - This is not entity framework. This is `LINQ query`. Just import : `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I don't want to use System.LINQ

Comment: @Rahul - Huh..Why so? Just curious to know. You like lengthy codes?

Comment: No dude!! I am working on a system which does not use all these references,
And I just have to fix a small portion in that.

Comment: @Rahul you didn't mention those 2 facts in your question

Comment: @fubo - Point taken :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var Type in TypeList)
{
    if (TypeArray.Contains(Type.Value.ToLower()))
    {
        IsValidType = true;
        break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: the second `ToLower()` seems to be missing

Comment: Strin[] not use .Contains()

Comment: @Rahul it does. its Linq.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want Linq (as you mentioned in comments) then here is some improvements.

```
foreach (var Type in TypeList)
{
    if (Array.FindIndex(TypeArray, singleType => 
        singleType.Equals(Type.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) > -1)
    {
        IsValidType = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this only needs `System` namespace. the minimum requirements!

Comment: of course behind the other namespaces you have like `System.Collections.Generic`

Answer (score 0):

Import LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Use the following lambda expression to achieve what you want.

```
bool IsValidType = TypeList.Any(x => TypeArray.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```